# should I use preventDefualt() or stopPropagation() in this jquery and how?

Tags: jquery, toggle, preventdefault

```
var flip1 = 0;
$( ".car-row" ).click(function() {
    $( ".car-types" ).toggle( );
});
```

When div class ".car-row" is clicked, its subdiv '.cartypes' is toggled.

```
$('input[name=allcheck-cars]').click(function() {
    $("input[name='checkbox']").prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

On clicking the checkbox, I just want the checkboxes in the subdiv to be     checked/unchecked which I am able to do it. At the same time, when I click this checkbox which is in the same div class ".car-row", the subdiv ".cartypes" again gets toggled which            I dont want to happen. So I need   to use `.preventDefault()` anywhere to prevent toggling subdiv on click of checkbox. Please help.

http://jsfiddle.net/zMPJQ/

Comment: can you provide fiddle?

Comment: get a jsfiddle ready mr!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zMPJQ/   here on clicking checkbox, the other checkboxes should not toggle. subcheckboxes should be toggled only on clicking the .car-row div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you  need to do is add capture the first parameter in the anonymous function, which contains the event. On this event you can call the preventDefault.

```
$('input[name=allcheck-cars]').click(function(e){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $("input[name='checkbox']").prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Comment: My appologies, what you need is stopPropagation(), edited in the answer above and in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zMPJQ/2/